# SSL installed on Apache2 but HTTPS not working

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-ec2, firewall, iptables

I recently installed an SSL certificate on my Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 12.04(32bit) server running Apache 2.

When I attempt to access my site via https, it does not load. When I perform an nmap scan, i see that port 443 is not open.

I tried to open port 443 in my ip tables to no avail. `iptables -L` yeilds

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
```

Here's how I installed ssl

I modified /etc/init.d/apache2.conf to include ssl.conf and modified ssl.conf to include the requisite 
paths of my certificate files, ie

SSLCertificateFile /path/file
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/file
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/file

I configured my security group to allow inbound requests from port 443 (TCP source:0.0.0.0/0)

When I perform the following test with php

```
if (!extension_loaded('openssl')) 
{
  echo "not loaded";
}
else
{
  echo "loaded"   ;
}
```

I get "loaded".

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens when you try opening a telnet connection from a remote machine to your server on port 443?  Does it connect?  If so, then you can rule out a firewall or routing problem, or a problem with iptables.  I would also be curious if your apache logs are showing anything interesting.

Comment: telnet to 443 returns "Connection Refused". Nothing is appended to apache logs when I attempt to access https://mydomain.net

Comment: Interesting.  How about if you try a loopback connection, from the host itself, on port 443?  In other words, telnet localhost 443.  Does that connect?  I'm trying to isolate whether this is an apache issue or a networking / firewall issue.

Comment: Ahh looks like an apache issue. Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In httpd-ssl.conf, do you have 
    Listen 443

If not, try adding that, and restarting apache.

Comment: I did not. While I'm using apache2.conf(ubuntu thing?) to load an external ssl.conf, I did not have this directive anywhere. Adding it directly to my apache conf and reconfiguring virtual host directive / mod_ssl.so include resolved things. Thanks

Comment: This worked for me as well, only I had to modify "ports.conf"

Comment: in apache 2.4 the file is `ports.conf`

Comment: @Bakhshi--that depends on your distribution of apache, your platform, and the default configuration...  xampp distributes apache 2.4.*  on windows with the ssl settings in httpd-ssl.conf, it is port 443 is enabled by default...  the virtual host section in this file needs some alteration to point to a specific domain, but it's not in ports.conf

Comment: You could make it the first line of your conf file, outside the tags, always works

Comment: Thanks, spent an hour trying to figure this out and all along the problem was ports.conf

Answer (score 24):

First check if mod_ssl is enabled. If not, enable it by running a2enmod ssl. Then check if Apache is listening on port 443 for https. Then check if the firewall is not blocking port 443.

Comment: Me too. Please check your Inbound firewall ports, 443 in this case.

Comment: Thanks bro, You saved me.

Answer (score 23):

**Edit: from comments, the following is true for AWS Lightsail, Oracle Cloud, IONOS, and probably many other managed web hosts:**

If anyone else finds this and is using Amazon Lightsail (like me), you have to use their web UI to explicitly open port 443.

I spent hours pouring over my server config files before I discovered that :/

Comment: You're a lifesaver

Comment: Thank you, this was the hint for me. I had an EC2 instance linked to a Security Group with no inbound rule for HTTPS (443).

Comment: Thank you! Totally missed this one

Comment: if anyone is on oracle cloud, same thing!

Comment: Same for IONOS.

Answer (score 7):

In httpd.conf the following is disabled by default:

```
# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
# Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

Simply remove the # from the Include and restart Apache.

Comment: I'm probably going to leave on work time now thanks to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you can connect locally (e.g. with `telnet localhost 443` as mti suggests), check if the firewall is configured properly.

In my case, `ufw` was blocking everything, so I had to `ufw allow 443` which fixed the underlying problem to the same symptom.

Comment: Thanks, this idea helped us figure out our issue.  For us it was the corporate firewall though, so people should consider that as well.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a situation where there was a process listening on port 443, the firewall was completely open, SELinux was disabled, and I *still* couldn't telnet to port 443. Not even from the localhost. I kept getting:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 443
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused`
```

It turns out the iptables NAT table had some rules redirect traffic coming in on port 443 to a different port (8443). Nothing was listening on port 8443.

```
# iptables --table nat --list
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https redir ports 8443
```

Removing the relevant NAT entries fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This was exactly the issue I was having. I think the NAT rules were in place to service a VM running on my server, although as that has its own (bridged) IP those rules are not necessary.

Comment: This was mine, for some reason when I restarted Apache it decided to switch from port 8443 to 443...redirect was the problem then.

Answer (score 1):

For me it's the stupid Chrome cache. `Ctrl + Shift + Del` to clear the cache, restart Chrome, and SSL is correctly working now.

Answer (score 0):

If the SSL keys are not set (or were inexplicably commented out by gremlins), Apache 2.2 SSL will silently fail. There will be no error in the log, and it will not be listening to 443. The http:80 sites will work.

Answer (score 0):

First, Check processes on port "80" and "443" `sudo netstat -peanut | grep ':80'` and `*sudo netstat -peanut | grep ':443'*` .If 443 is has no process then this would help:
Editing the Apache configuration file to serve the cert works well.
Use the command `sudo certbot --apache`
You are good

Answer (score -6):

Sometimes an *iptables -F* works. I had the port 443 open for inbound in Amazon, but still the site was not opening in my browser.

Logged on to the site, gave an iptables -F and immediately the site was accessible.

Comment: iptables -F will delete all your firewall rules. Not a good idea. http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html